# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph in makebox and tabular

Tags: texpad, macos

I'm using makebox and tabular with `\\` to make empty line. As per my understanding it seems it is bad behaviour to use `\\` then how to manage the empty line? Thank you

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent \makebox[3cm][l]{Nama} : name\\
\makebox[3cm][l]{NIS} : number code\\
\makebox[3cm][l]{Judul} : title)\\\\
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Cilacap, 07 September 2017}                                                                    \\
Menyetujui,                                      &             & Siswa                                            \\
Mentor                                           &             &                                                  \\
                                                 &             &                                                  \\
                                                 &             &                                                  \\
                                                 &             &                                                  \\
(someone) &             & (someone) \\
                                                 &             &                                                  \\
                                                 & Mengetahui, &                                                  \\
someone                               &             & someone                                \\
                                                 &             &                                                  \\
                                                 &             &                                                  \\
                                                 &             &                                                  \\
(\hrulefill) &             & (\hrulefill)
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Either use `\\[\baselineskip]` instead of ` \\\\ ` or use an empty line for a paragraph break followed e.g. with `\medskip`

Comment: using `\\[\baselineskip]` solved the problems. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By using `\null` between `\\\\` (`\\\null\\`), this can be avoided.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent \makebox[3cm][l]{Nama} : name\\
\makebox[3cm][l]{NIS} : number code\\
\makebox[3cm][l]{Judul} : title)\\\null\\
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Cilacap, 07 September 2017}                                                                    \\
Menyetujui,                                      &             & Siswa                                            \\
Mentor                                           &             &                                                  \\
                                                 &             &                                                  \\
                                                 &             &                                                  \\
                                                 &             &                                                  \\
(someone) &             & (someone) \\
                                                 &             &                                                  \\
                                                 & Mengetahui, &                                                  \\
someone                               &             & someone                                \\
                                                 &             &                                                  \\
                                                 &             &                                                  \\
                                                 &             &                                                  \\
(\hrulefill) &             & (\hrulefill)
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Hope this helps.